# deleting rows in Firebase Analytics export to BigQuery with less popular values

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Before sharing a Firebase Analyics table in BigQuery with third parties, I need to remove the rows with cities that show up in less than 5 rows. How can I do this, without losing the table structure?

Challenges:

- Firebase Analytics data in BigQuery has nested rows, and I don't want to lose the nested structure.
- Some cities in different regions have the same name. This means I need to use at least two fields (city, region) when counting.
- Sometimes city and/or region can be null. I don't want to lose those rows.

Answer (score 3):

Quick query:

```
SELECT *,
  IFNULL(user_dim.geo_info.city,'_')+IFNULL(user_dim.geo_info.region,'_') cityregion, 
FROM [dataset.app_events_20160607]
HAVING cityregion NOT IN (
  SELECT cityregion FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) c, IFNULL(user_dim.geo_info.city,'_')+IFNULL(user_dim.geo_info.region,'_') cityregion
    FROM [dataset.app_events_20160607]
    GROUP BY 2
    HAVING c<6
  )
)
```

You'll have to set options to:

- Allow large results
- Not flatten results

Quick explanation:

- `SELECT *, [...] cityregion` brings in all the results without losing structure and adding a new column `cityregion`.
- `IFNULL(..., '_') replaces null values with`_`, so we can combine city and region together in case one is null.
- `HAVING cityregion NOT IN` looks at the new `cityregion` column, to check if it doesn't exist in the sub-query.
- The sub-query counts each combination of city-region, and only lists those that appear less than 6 times.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you cannot "afford" having extra redundant column in your public data
Haven't tested, but below should do this - you will just need to run it in [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)

```
SELECT *
FROM `dataset.app_events_20160607`
WHERE CONCAT(IFNULL(user_dim.geo_info.city,'_'), IFNULL(user_dim.geo_info.region,'_')) NOT IN (
  SELECT cityregion FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) c, CONCAT(IFNULL(user_dim.geo_info.city,'_'), IFNULL(user_dim.geo_info.region,'_')) cityregion
    FROM `dataset.app_events_20160607`
    GROUP BY 2
    HAVING c<6
  )
)
```